# Stored Functions with mongo_fdw

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, stored-procedures

Can I call stored JS procedures from PostgreSQL using mongo_fdw?
If it can be done, how? If not, why and can it be done by other FDW such as postgres_fdw?

(I'm using the latest version of PostgreSQL, MongoDB and mongo_fdw on Ubuntu 12.04.3)

Comment: stored JS procedures ARE NOT THE EQUIVALENT OF STORED PROCEDURES

Comment: From my research they are the closest thing available >.<

Comment: Nope not even close, they run completely differently

Comment: I edited the question accordingly, thanks for making things clear for me

Comment: Postgres docs on [Creating Foreign Data Wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/fdw-callbacks.html) don't suggest there are any standard callbacks implemented outside of user and data access. The [`postgres_fwd`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html) module also doesn't mention calling remote Postgres stored procs, so I suspect this isn't possible yet. If you want to do crazy things in Postgres, you could always use one of the supported extension languages like PL/Python or PL/Perl to call out to MongoDB. I wouldn't expect performance or stability though ;-).

Comment: Pls. mark the actual versions instead of "the latest". SO questions often remain relevant for years.